# Desktop and taskbar dissapearing/refreshing constantly

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, desktop

My desktop goes completely black, and my taskbar icons and desktop icons clear and then load back on after it goes black. Windows 10. It just started happening last week or so, but this refreshing process happens every 30 seconds or so and it slows the whole computer down and brings me out of anything full screen. Also if I have Task manager open windows explorer goes up like to 10% of cpu usage... it is extremely frustrating. Looks like sihost.exe goes up as well in cpu usage.
More about : desktop taskbar disappear comp

Comment: It sounds like the Explorer process is crashing and relaunching. Try opening the Reliability Monitor (search 'reliability' from Start Menu) to see if it reports anything strange. Perhaps upload a screenshot of what the graph shows.

Comment: Have you tried system restore? This solved the exact problem for me.

Comment: I would run Process Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and look at the list of modules loaded into Explorer.exe. See the bottom pane.  Maybe sort by the Company Name column to exclude Microsoft.  The properties of each will show you the auto-start location for example.  You could maybe disable a few.  Ideally you'd create a dump file of Explorer.exe when it crashes with something like procdump.exe and see what the crashing stack looks like but disabling a few modules should be quite quick and you'll know quickly if disabling one helps.

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me is changing a registry key that was changed by a system optimization application. That optimize application said that it needs to change that `DesktopProcess` registry key value to `1` to "avoid system crashes". And when I did allow that optimize app to change the `DesktopProcess` value to `1` then the desktop, the desktop icons, explorer, and taskbar kept on refreshing randomly (and, I also had an icon disappear from the taskbar tray menu). I looked at the logs of that optimization application and found that indeed the `DesktopProcess` key value was changed to `1` by that optimize app. I went into registry and changed it back to the value of `0`, rebooted the computer; and the refreshing problem stopped entirely.

Registry Key:

1. Open the registry editor
2. Go to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
3. Click on `DesktopProcess`
4. Change the `DesktopProcess` registry key value from `1` to the value `0`
5. Reboot the computer

I have found a reference to the `DesktopProcess` registry key, link below.

Reference source: http://systemmanager.ru/win2k_regestry.en/58864.htm

If that link were to go out, I am pasting the content of the above source reference link.

```
DesktopProcess 
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Data type   Range   Default value 
REG_DWORD   0 | 1   0 

Description
Determines whether the components of Windows 2000 Explorer
run in a single process or in two separate processes.

Value   Meaning 
0       All of the components of Windows Explorer (Explorer,
Desktop, and Taskbar) run as separate threads in a single,
multithreaded process called Explorer.exe. 
1       All instances of Windows
Explorer run in one process and the Desktop and Taskbar run in a
separate process. Both processes are called Explorer.exe. 

Windows 2000 does not add this entry to the registry. You can add it
by editing the registry or by using a program that edits the registry.

Tip

To verify that DesktopProcess is enabled, use the Processes tab in
Task Manager. If the value of DesktopProcess is 1, at least two
instances of the Explorer.exe process should appear in the list of
processes (one for the Desktop and Taskbar and one for Windows
Explorer). For each additional instance of Windows Explorer, a new
instance of Explorer.exe should appear in the list of processes.

Caution

Enabling DesktopProcess can interfere with the functions of Windows
Explorer if the computer is not equipped to run all processes
efficiently. Do not set the value of DesktopProcess to 1 unless the
computer has a Pentium processor (or equivalent) and at least 16 MB of
physical random access memory.
```